# Выделение текущей ссылки

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый вечер, дорогие программисты! Надеюсь, вы можете мне помочь. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Мне нужно выделить активную ссылку в меню. Меню находится в мастер-странице. Я ищу лучший способ осуществить это. Любые идеи.

Comment: @ArsenARM, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Из view наследника, который знает об активном пункте меню, передать в базовую мастер-страницу признак активного меню (имя или что-либо другое, на ваш вкус). Выбор пути передачи также оставляю на ваш выбор. )) Для примера пусть это будет ViewBag.